# Phonegap background issue

Tags: android, css, cordova, phonegap-build

[image: background over contenet (Wrong)]

I'm trying to develop an application via phonegap and there is a very strange issue, after building the application sometimes background color overlay the content, generally when I relaunch my app it works properly

[image: right version]
my css

```
 body {
       background: #1abc9c;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

set it as

background-color:#1abc9c;